# Low download Mbps and high upload Mbps

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem, internet-speed

I am currently working on a java project for a client that is based in Shanghai. They're a school and they have a central based network and multiple smaller LANs attached to that network. They have extremely slow internet but said they have purchased one of the fastest based internet rate packages from their ISPs. I did a couple of tests and my own research and it seems they have a bottleneck in their hardware (most likely modem). The tested rates are down below and were re-checked.

```
7, 0.24 showed but was reduced down to 0.09 right when dl scan finished with 2.29 up speeds at 7:00 PM
7, 0.08 with 3.31 up speeds at 8:00 PM
7, 0.31 with 4.20 up speeds at 9:00 PM
7, 0.13 with 1.31 up speeds at 10:00 PM
7, 0.34 with 2.67 up speeds at 11:00 PM
7, 0.57 with 6.76 up speeds at 12:00 AM
8, 0.89 with 13.78 up speeds at 1:00 AM
8, 3.13 with 16.26 up speeds at 7:00 AM
7, 4.76 with 20.50 up speeds at 7:30 AM
```

Their peak hours are between 10 AM and 2 PM. Due to the school being a boarding school they have students accessing the net at various hours. My java project which requires internet can't possibly function in these speeds especially at the peak hours so I was hoping I could help them clarify a little bit on their issue because the dl/up ratios were just too far off. I currently have a theory that their modem is overheating due to the enormous amount of devices online at a time, around 300-400 at peak hours, and 100-200 consistently. I wanted to know if I am correct in assuming that and if any other possible explanation would be more reasonable?

EDIT: So it's 8:00 AM now. I just ran a test and got 8 ping, dl went immediately up to 10 mbps but then started steadily dropping and so the test never completed.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern doesn't seem to be a hardware failure as much as it seems to be a usage bottleneck. Without knowing exactly what kind of ISP they have, but knowing that during what you're calling peak hours they're getting between 50 and 100mb/s possible download, it seems like if they have a 50mb/s connection it's entirely possible that the bottleneck is caused by their usage.